# Store reference to an AuraEnabled Apex method in a JS property

Tags: lightning-web-components, aura-enabled

Is it possible to store a dynamic reference to an AuraEnabled Apex method in the LWC JavaScript controller? Something like this:

```
import myMethodA from '@salesforce/apex/MyController.myMethodA';
import myMethodB from '@salesforce/apex/MyController.myMethodB';

export default class bdObjectSyncItem extends LightningElement {
    action;

    connectedCallback() {
        // determine which action to invoke based on the condition
        // obviously this calls the method --> problem
        this.action = (condition) ? 
            myMethodA({ param: 'paramA' }) : 
            myMethodB({ param: 'paramB' });

        // now invoke the action
        this.action.then(data => { ... })
    }
}
```

In the above code block, the resulting method gets called right at the time of the assignment -which is not desirable. I want to be able to store it in a property and then call it when I'm ready. Is it possible?

Comment: Does this `this.action = condition ? myMethodA : myMethodB;` not achieve that?

Comment: @KeithC Yes, that worked. If you wish to turn that into an answer I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: Ok Mossi, done, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript you can pass around and assign functions just like other variables; functions are objects that have special capabilities e.g. they can be executed via `()`.

So in this case:

```
this.action = condition ? myMethodA : myMethodB;
```

and then later you can invoke the function:

```
this.action(arguments);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that. I have tried using below piece of code and it works fine. I have created a property which will store the method based on condition. The type of property when it store method is the function. On load of the component, I am storing the right method in property and using a button click, I am calling the method.

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import getUserId from '@salesforce/apex/ContactController.getUserId';
import apexMethod from '@salesforce/apex/ContactController.apexMethod';
export default class ParentGetterComponent extends LightningElement {
    condition = false;
    resultvalue;
    error;
    method;
    connectedCallback() {
        console.log('typeof ' + typeof getUserId);
        console.log('typeof ' + typeof apexMethod);
        this.method = this.condition ? getUserId() : apexMethod({ z: new Date() });
        console.log('method' + this.method);
    }
    handleLoad() {
        this.method.then(result => {
            this.resultvalue = result;
        }).catch(error => {
            this.error = JSON.stringify(error);
        });
    }
}
```

And HTML file:-

```
<template>
    <p class="slds-m-bottom_small">
        <lightning-button label="Load Contacts" onclick={handleLoad}></lightning-button>
    </p>
    <div class="slds-card">
        Result - {resultvalue}
    </div>
    <div class="slds-card">
        Error - {error}
    </div>
</template>
```

Result:-

[image]

### UPDATE

You can store the method to be called in the property any point of the time. Either it is connectedCallback or any method or using getter.

Comment: Yes. That works, but the Apex method gets called in `connectedCallback` at the time of assignment. And that's not the behaviour I'm looking for.

Comment: When are you looking for? You can do it in the same way anywhere else too.